# multiple assertions in a single statement in cypress

Tags: chai, cypress

I am trying to assert visibility of the child elements in a parent element.

i am checking weather the divs inside c-cost-with label are visible.

Here is the HTML for it:

[image: HTML Content]

i am trying to fetch the elements based on the parent:

```
    Given(/^I should see the following charge amounts and charge labels in offer:$/, (dataTable) => {
    dataTable.rawTable.slice(1).forEach((row) => {
        let [optionName, pricingPlanName, chargeAmount, ChargeLabel] = row;
        let costWithLabelElement = costWithLabelUtil.getCostWithLabelElement(optionsCardCostListElement);
        costWithLabelUtil.getCostWithLabelCostElementContainingText(chargeAmount, costWithLabelElement).should('be.visible');
        costWithLabelUtil.getCostWithLabelLabelElementContainingText(ChargeLabel, costWithLabelElement).should('be.visible');

    });
});
```

here is the code in costWithLabelUtil:

```
    export function getCostWithLabelElement (ancestorElement = null) {
    return ElementFinders.getElementFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label', ancestorElement);
}


export function getCostWithLabelMainElement (ancestorElement = null) {
    return ElementFinders.getElementFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label__main', ancestorElement);
}


export function getCostWithLabelCostElement (ancestorElement = null) {
    return ElementFinders.getElementFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label__cost', ancestorElement);
}

export function getCostWithLabelCostElementContainingText (text, ancestorElement = null) {
    return ElementFinders.getElementContainingTextFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label__cost', text, ancestorElement);
}

export function getCostWithLabelLabelElement (ancestorElement = null) {
    return ElementFinders.getElementFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label__label', ancestorElement);
}

export function getCostWithLabelLabelElementContainingText (text, ancestorElement = null) {
    cy.log(ancestorElement);
    return ElementFinders.getElementContainingTextFromAncestorIfProvided('.c-cost-with-label__label', text, ancestorElement);
}
```

Here is the Element Finder page:

```
    export function getElementFromAncestorIfProvided (elementLocator, ancestorElement = null) {
    if (ancestorElement) {
        return ancestorElement.find(elementLocator);
    }

    return cy.get(elementLocator);
}


export function getElementContainingTextFromAncestorIfProvided (elementLocator, text, ancestorElement = null) {
    if (ancestorElement) {
        return ancestorElement.find(elementLocator).contains(text);
    }

    return cy.get(elementLocator).contains(text);
}
```

I am fetching the parent element first and then trying to fetch the childs and check there visibility.

when i execute the steps the first step is executed correctly but the second step is failing !!!

[image: Fail]

it is trying to fetch the element from '.c-cost-with-label__cost' even though in the function i am passing the parent element.

how to resolve this issue, how to perform assertions [check visibility] on different elements simultaneously

Comment: The error is saying it's looking for `.c-cost-with-label__label` as a child of `.c-cost-with-label__cost`, which it isn't - it's a sibling.  It's hard to give a better answer of exactly where you went wrong because you've abstracted the actual cypress code away from the code you posted, I'd only be guessing as to what happens in `costWithLabelUtil`

Comment: hi @Brendan I have updated the question with the code of costWithUtil and Element Finder functions

Comment: try changing `costWithLabelUtil.getCostWithLabelLabelElementContainingText(ChargeLabel, costWithLabelElement).should('be.visible');` to `costWithLabelUtil.getCostWithLabelLabelElementContainingText(ChargeLabel, optionsCardCostListElement).should('be.visible');`

Comment: @Brendan cypress passed the first assertion, but it is not going in to second line to check c-cost-with-label__label element

Comment: what was the error message?

Comment: no error message, cypress keep running

Comment: post a screen shot of your command log

Comment: cypress not issuing any errors, it is running indefinitely.

here is the video of the run :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4dyzH9J44M&feature=youtu.be

Comment: the youtube link doesn't work

Comment: @Brendan  I am sorry it is in private mode, now you can access the link

Comment: hard to say, the abstraction/framework you've placed over the cypress commands makes it difficult to understand what's going on.  I'd suggest trying to write the command out with cypress directly and seeing if you can get it working with a regular `cy.get(".c-cost-with-label__label").should("be.visible")`.  if that works then you'll have to look through that extra code to see what went wrong.